# How to convert RGBA to RGB in Python, or how to get the right color code

Tags: python, colors, rgba

Thanks in advance!
Below is the html, and I use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@class='title-part form_title']").value_of_css_property('color')` to catch the color, but the result is `rgba(63,64,64,1)`, but my expect result is **#3f3f40**.

Question1: is there any way to get the correct color code by python directly?
Question2: if not, is there any way to convert the **rgba(63,64,64,1)** to **rgb** code? so that I can user`'#%02x%02x%02x' % (rgb)` to get the color code?
Help! Help! Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert the rgba tuple into a hex value, it's pretty straight-forward and there's some code here that shows you how to achieve it: https://pythonjunkie.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/convert-hex-color-values-to-rgb-in-python/

`def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
...   return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb`